# How to convert a list of counters into a list with items and values combined in python?

Tags: python, string, counter

I have

```
x = [('a', 1), ('ab', 1), ('abc', 1), ('abcd', 1), ('b', 1), ('bc', 1), ('bcd', 1), ('c', 1), ('cd', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

I want to convert each of the elements in x such that:

```
('a',1) --> 'a1';

('ab', 1) --> 'ab1';

('abc', 1) --> 'abc1';
```

For your reference:

This is how I got x: `x = list(Counter(words).items())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3.6+, you can use a list comprehension and an f-string:

```py
x = [('a', 1), ('ab', 1), ('abc', 1), ('abcd', 1), ('b', 1), ('bc', 1), ('bcd', 1), ('c', 1), ('cd', 1), ('d', 1)]
output = [f'{first}{second}' for first, second in x]
```

If you are using a previous version:

```
output = ['{first}{second}'.format(first=first, second=second) for first, second in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
x = [('a', 1), ('ab', 1), ('abc', 1), ('abcd', 1), ('b', 1), ('bc', 1), ('bcd', 1), ('c', 1), ('cd', 1), ('d', 1)]
comb = [tup[0]+str(tup[1]) for tup in x]
```